# Преобразование строки с экранированными символами Unicode к исходному виду

Tags: c#, unicode

Есть строка следующего содержимого:
`@"bla bla bla \u041a\u043e\u043c bla bla bla"`
Т.е. кирилические символы я получаю в юникоде. Как такую строку переобразовать в обычный `string` не выдумывая адских велосипедных механизмов на паровом ходу?

Comment: Вы получаете не строку, а какой-то ужас. Откуда вы её получаете? Это важно.

Comment: @VladD , API сайта. Результат даёт в JSON формате. Всё помимо кирилицы дает в нормальной кодировке, а с кирилицей вот такая вот фигня.

Comment: Так, а что вы делаете со входящим JSON'ом? Надеюсь, вы не пытаетесь интерпретировать его как строку и регулярками выкусывать из него куски? (Если да, это и есть велосипед, и из-за него у вас и проблема.)

Comment: @VladD , Да, просто выкусываю значения по ключах. WPF проект, стандартных средств для работы с JSON, как я понимаю, - нет. Мне хватало бы и обычного выкусывания кода. Что-то мне подсказывает что даже при использовании чего-то более специального проблема с кодировкой может остаться :/ Или же стоит что-то попробовать?

Comment: _стандартных средств для работы с JSON, как я понимаю, - нет_ - ещё как есть! [JavaScriptSerializer](https://msdn.microsoft.com/ru-ru/library/system.web.script.serialization.javascriptserializer%28v=vs.110%29.aspx), [DataContractJsonSerializer](https://msdn.microsoft.com/ru-ru/library/system.runtime.serialization.json.datacontractjsonserializer%28v=vs.110%29.aspx). В последнее время стандартом де-факто стала библиотека [Json.NET](https://json.codeplex.com/).

Comment: О боги, "не выдумывая адских велосипедных механизмов на паровом ходу" и "мне хватало бы и обычного выкусывания кода" в одном параграфе. о_О

Comment: @Discord , дело в том что из огроменного ответа мне надо всего 3 поля. Парсить всё сразу не обязательно. Но уже сделал на JavaScriptSerializer, вполне неплохо.

Comment: @GrM: Вот именно эта экономия («мне всё равно только 3 поля надо») и есть велосипед и причина вашей проблемы. Потому что для того, чтобы распарсить JSON, **недостаточно** «выкусить три поля», ваш вопрос это доказывает. И бог знает сколько ещё особенностей формата JSON вам придётся учитывать. Пользуйтесь парсером, короче.

Answer (score 1):

Начнём с того, что такую строку изначально не надо обрабатывать. Или сервер дважды экранирует строку (например, дважды сериализует в JSON), и тогда нужно починить сервер, или клиент читает строчки напрямую, игнорируя формат отдаваемых данных (например, JSON), и тогда нужно починить клиент.

Если вы всё-таки настаиваете на костыльном способе решении проблемы, то вам может подойти `Regex.Unescape` — в регулярных выражениях используется схожее экранирование. Если вы знаете источник экранирования, то можете прицепить его костыльным способом, например, можно использовать `JsonConvert.DeserializeObject<string>("\"" + s + "\"")`.

Comment: Что-то у меня сомнения насчёт `Regex.Unescape`.

Comment: @Discord: Вы были правы, почитайте каменты к вопросу.